# Preservation of complements under mappings and inverse mappings.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Let $T:X\to Y$ be a mapping between metric spaces, from $X$ into $Y$. Consider any $U\subseteq Y$. Now consider the inverse image of $Y\backslash U$, let's call it $Z\subseteq X$. My question is will $T$ definitely map $X\backslash Z$ into $U$? I.e is it true that $$T(X\backslash Z)=U$$ I want to use this result as part of another proof, but as $T$ is a functional relation and not a nice function I wasn't sure if my intuition was correct, and I haven't been able to come up with a proof as we aren't guaranteed that $T$ even has an inverse. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to assume that the domain and codomain are metric spaces as you do not use any of that structure. Arbitrary sets will do.

While it is true that $T(X\setminus Z)\subset U$, it is not true that this holds with equality (**hint**: what happens when $T$ is not surjective?).

To see the claim holds with containment (but not equality), let $x$ denote an arbitrary element of $X\setminus Z$. Clearly, $T(x)$ is not in $Y\setminus U$ since otherwise $x$ would be in $Z$. Therefore, $x$ is in $Y\setminus(Y \setminus U)=U$.

Comment: Yes of course, the equality was silly of me. What I'm actually more interested in is if we can say that $X\backslash Z$ is the inverse image of $U$?

Comment: Certainly the preimage of $U$ must contain $X\setminus Z$. Can it be a bigger set?

Comment: I think that will actually suffice for my proof thank you (I get that if it's not surjective it can certainly be bigger.) We have $\forall x \in X\backslash Z$ then $T(x) \in U$.Now if $x \notin X\backslash Z$ then $x \in Z$ so $T(x) \notin U$ by our definition. Correct? That seems to be Kreyszig's definition of an inverse image so that will suffice for my proof. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are just asking, given $f:X \to Y$, whether it is generally true that $$X\setminus f^{-1}(Y\setminus U)=f^{-1}(U)$$
The answer is yes. To see this, just note that

$$x\in X\setminus f^{-1}(Y\setminus U) \iff x\notin f^{-1}(Y\setminus U)$$
$$\iff f(x)\notin Y\setminus U$$
$$\iff f(x)\in Y\setminus (Y\setminus U)\equiv U$$
$$\iff x\in f^{-1}(U)$$

Comment: As $T$ is just a general mapping we can't assume that an inverse $T^{-1}$ exists unfortunately.

Comment: @K.Power In MPW's post, $f^{-1}$ denotes the preimage, i.e. $f^{-1}(B) = \{x \in X \mid f(x) \in B\}$ for all $B \subseteq Y$. This function always exists.